# Can't insert with sql the date which i picked from calendar

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to do a project from university and I can't figure out how to insert the date which I pick from calendar function. I have tried a couple of things, but I get 0000-00-00 or the current date: 2014-06-08.

```php
<?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$checkin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['checkin']);
$checkout = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['checkout']);
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['title']);
$roomtype = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['roomtype']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phone']);


$checkout = date("Y-m-d");



$sql="INSERT INTO reservation (checkin, checkout, firstname, lastname, title, roomtype, email, phone)
VALUES ('$checkin', '$checkout', '$firstname','$lastname', '$title', '$roomtype', '$email', '$phone')";



if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

echo "Your booking has been completed";
mysqli_close($con);

header("Location: ");  
   exit;  
?>
```

Comment: Please `echo` the value of `$sql` right  before you use `mysqli_query()` and let us know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably with your html form. HTML5 allows for an easy date picker:

```
<input type="date" name="checkin">
<input type="date" name="checkout">
```

You dont need value="DD/MM/YY" and onfocus and those other arguments. If a date input is left empty it will return nothing. The input also outputs the date as a unix timestamp I believe

Comment: The inputs from my hmtl form are:

    <input class="checkin" id="datepicker" type="date" value="DD/MM/YY" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'DD/MM/YY';}">
    <input class="date" id="datepicker1" type="date" value="DD/MM/YY" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'DD/MM/YY';}">

Comment: You dont need value="DD/MM/YY" and onfocus and those other arguments. If a date input is left empty it will return nothing. The input also outputs the date as a unix timestamp I believe

Comment: well if i usee only the following code my calendar script doesn't work and it doesn't pop up the little calendar window so i can pick the date i want...

    <input type="date" name="checkin">
    <input type="date" name="checkout">

Comment: IE and FireFox doesnt support the html5 date picker so you will need to use safari or chrome. Its html5 feature and no other javascript classes are needed

Comment: Well it worked when i submit the booking form i have made for my project from chrome but i want a solution that will work with all browsers because when i will present my project they probably not use chrome or safari.

Comment: I used this before I knew about the html5 date picker: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: I am gonna try this one also.If you have spare time can you check my calendar the way i had it in my html from : http://dev.medialab.teicrete.gr/3597/index.html and how it looks like with just <input type="date" name="checkin"> from: http://dev.medialab.teicrete.gr/3597/availability.html

Comment: Your missing name="" in the input tags

Comment: In which line? i didn't see any "" missing.

Comment: On http://dev.medialab.teicrete.gr/3597/index.html on all input tags the name is missing

Comment: On this page isn't necessary name="" because i am not sending any info throught php to my sql database.Only my contact.html and availability.html inserting into sql's tables infos.

Answer (score 1):

```
$checkout = date("Y-m-d");
```

The function give you the current date in the format "Y-m-d" That is the first reason why you get the current date and because you save the current date after you did : `$checkout = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['checkout']);` you override the date you get with `$_POST['checkout']`

You should do this:

```
$checkout = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['checkout']);
$checkout = date_format(date_create($checkout), 'Y-m-d');
```

Comment: i still get the 0000-00-00 for date inside the table

Comment: this could be a problem with your database, i had the same problem some time ago where my column was a false type and because of this i got only 0000-00-00 but it could be also possible that your $_POST['checkout'] give you this date.

Comment: like i see there are some with the right date or not? how did they got the right date? try to `var_dump($checkout)` to know what is in the variable after your `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: with $checkout = date('Y-m-d'); i got the timestamp and i got the current date and not the one i picked...

Comment: yeah i know, but then the $_POST['checkout'] variable is empty or something like this. then date_create would create a date with 0000-00-00 like you said and that will be inserted in your database